# How can I have a dynamic array without using a vector? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

The program question is as follows:

Write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. That list is followed by two more integers representing lower and upper bounds of a range. Your program should output all integers from the list that are within that range (inclusive of the bounds). For coding simplicity, follow each output integer by a comma, even the last one. The output ends with a newline.

My professor is asking me to do this program without the use of vectors. However I can't seem to understand that without a user inputting the total number of indices for the array. When I do try the way with the comments I made I get the error:

> Exited with return code -11 (SIGSEGV)

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int i;
   int userARR;
   const int NUM_ARR = 5;
   int inputList[NUM_ARR];
   int minR;
   int maxR;
   
   //cin >> userARR;
   
   //i < userARR;?
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_ARR; ++i) {
      cin >> inputList[i];
   }
   
   cin >> minR >> maxR;
   
   //i < userARR;?
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_ARR; ++i) {
      if ((inputList[i] >= minR) && (inputList[i] <= maxR)) {
         cout << inputList[i] << ",";
      }
   }
   
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: _" The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow."_

Comment: `cout << inputList[i] << ",";` -- You will have a trailing `,` after the last item.  You need a bit more logic than this to remove the trailing `,`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the trailing comma follows the spec:   _For coding simplicity, follow each output integer by a comma, even the last one._

Comment: It's been a while since I did anything with C++, so my memory might be faulty. But, can't you do something like this:  `int arrSize; cin >> arrSize; int *inputList = new int (arrSize);` ?

Comment: @AviBerger -- I don't think you need an array -- the `NUM_ARR` is basically telling how many times to do a 1) `std::cin`, 2) test the number, 3) output the info, repeat 1,2,3....

Comment: @Chris -- ok.  Makes me think that the teacher had some trouble getting the comma to go away -- it's kind of weird that this stipulation was given.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer close. `int *inputList = new int[arrSize];`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie most likely the prof just wants them to tackle one problem at a time, and not get lost in details irrelevant to the current lesson.

Comment: @OP *My professor is asking me to do this program without the use of vectors.* -- So your professor didn't discuss anything beyond "don't use vectors"?  No discussion of `new[]` and `delete[]`?  If not, then either you are supposed to implement this as 1) Pete Becker mentioned, or 2) You were to do your own independent research and study of `new[]` and `delete[]` without the professor mentioning them or 3) You missed the lesson where `new[]` and `delete[]` was introduced by your professor.  So it's either choice 1) or 2) or 3).

Comment: Sorry, misread the problem statement. Yes, some sort of storage is needed. "The list is followed by two integers representing lower and upper bounds..."

Comment: @Chris -- Well, all I can say is that is one strange way to teach C++:  Never mention `new[]` and `delete[]` to the student, have them do independent research, but not have them do a simple task of not allowing a trailing comma.  Seems all upside-down to me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the actual list length is the first item in the input stream. NUM_ARR seems to be coming from nowhere and is not a part of or consistent with the posted problem statement. And the range for testing is only after. This forces the use of an array to store the numbers until they can be tested.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand the implications, but there a lot of assumptions from your comments that are not helping the question objective. I have not learned in any previous lessons of "new[]" and "delete[]". Everything I wrote above is everything I have learned so far and no other implication from my professor/class of independent research, as everything there is supposedly what I need to complete the program.

Comment: As far as everyone else thank you for the input and new knowledge. Extremely appreciated. However, I do need to complete the program only using the for loops, if statements, and the basic array without using a vector.

Comment: @SabinoMaggi -- Well, if you were not taught `new[]` and `delete[]` by your professor on purpose, then the implication *is* to do independent research as to how to create dynamic arrays without using vector.  What else is there to conclude from this?  If you got the information you need from posting your question, then that's the research the professor may have been looking for.  Bottom line -- either use `new[]` and `delete[]` or use the smart pointer using `[]` as suggested in one of the answers.  If you're looking for something simpler, you won't find it (other than using vector).

Comment: Your question was about having a dynamic array. The way to do that in C++ is with new[]/delete[] either directly or via some facility that handles it for you such as vector or make_unique. It is also possible to use malloc/free from the C library, though that use of C functionality is discouraged in modern C++. If you can't use one of those and aren't going to write your own memory allocator  or go directly to your OS's API, then the answer to your question about a dynamic array is: No, you cannot do this. Period.

Comment: Also, there is *no way* to resize a regular array, no matter how hard you may try using only the topics you have been taught in class up to this point.  That's the reason why it could be that the professor did this on purpose to not mention anything, and that purpose is to have you research the topic.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't intended to use a dynamic array, but have been given a max bound for the size of input and are supposed to use a fixed size non-dynamic array that is large enough to accommodate any input within that given limit. If that is the case, then the answer to this question "How can I have a dynamic array without using a vector? C++" is not relevant to what you are trying to do. The question you asked has been answered. It may not have been the question you actually wanted an answer to.

Comment: @AviBerger I do understand I not to use a dynamic array which as far as I know, is a vector. If I put the array index size to around 20 and then make an if statement if the user inputed array count is larger than that, I could re ask input from user to be less. I appreciate the response and the information.

Comment: I appreciate all the help. I figured it out. Sorry for the confusion and ignorance. I will be definitely looking back at this as a learning experience. Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C++ does not support variable length arrays (outside of compiler-specific extensions), you want to use a *dynamically allocated* array based on the input sample size. Such an array can be created with `new`, and then deallocated with `delete[]`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int sample, lower_bound, upper_bound;

  std::cin >> sample >> lower_bound >> upper_bound;

  auto arr = new int[sample];

  for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++) {
    std::cin >> arr[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++) {
    if (arr[i] >= lower_bound && arr[i] <= upper_bound) {
      std::cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  delete[] arr;

  return 0;
}
```

As a general rule, you should avoid using `new` and `delete` where possible, favoring `std::vector` in this scenario, but from an educational standpoint it's good to know how to use them.

If you wanted to avoid needing to explicitly deallocate you might alternately use a smart pointer which will handle the memory deallocation for you.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int sample, lower_bound, upper_bound;

  std::cin >> sample >> lower_bound >> upper_bound;

  auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(sample);

  for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++) {
    std::cin >> arr[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < sample; i++) {
    if (arr[i] >= lower_bound && arr[i] <= upper_bound) {
      std::cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


int main() {
  size_t listLength;
   
  // "The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow."
   
  std::cin >> listLength;
  // dynamically allocate the array
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> inputList = std::make_unique<int[]>(listLength);
  // if you can't use unique_ptr yet : 
  // int *inputList = new int[listLength];

  //gets a list of integers from input. 
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < listLength; ++i) {
      std::cin >> inputList[i];
   }

   //That list is followed by two more integers representing lower and upper bounds of a range. 
   int minR;
   int maxR;
   std::cin >> minR >> maxR;
   
   // Your program should output all integers from the list that are within that range (inclusive of the bounds)
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < listLength; ++i) {
      if ((inputList[i] >= minR) && (inputList[i] <= maxR)) {
         std::cout << inputList[i] << ",";
      }
   }  
   std::cout << std::endl;
   
  // release the dynamically allocated array (done automatically by unique_ptr when it goes out of scope
  // if you can't use unique_ptr yet : 
  // delete[] inputList;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to be modern enough to use smart pointers, I suggest also using `auto`. :)

Comment: @Chris, thought about it. Thought being explicit about types might be clearer, especially with all the confusion that seemed to be involved with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not need to know the number of elements in the range in advance. The number of elements in the range can at maximum be the number of all elements given. You know this number, that is the first number in the input.

```
The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow
```

Just create an array of size N, initialize all of the values to an `invalid` number. (e.g. lower_range - 1). Update the values of the array as you find numbers falling into the range.

During output, you can then only output the values that are not `invalid`.

However, that is if you really want to use arrays. @Pete Becker's proposition in the comments is much better and simpler approach.

Comment: @Pete Becker's proposition won't work for this problem as the range follows the list of numbers in the input. If the range was available before the list was input, it would have been a good suggestion. For the same reason, your algorithm as presented won't fly. Just read in all the numbers, than scan the array.

Comment: No, the approach I outlined doesn't work; the limits of the range come **after** the list of elements.